# Calling External JS Link in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css, page-flipping

I have 3 files for css, js, and php(which is more on html but i decided to put the php extension instead)
The project I'm trying to make is an interactive Menu that has a Page Flip action. I was able to find a reference in codepen. However, when I tried to apply it to my end, the animation and the text where not functioning the way I need it to be, although it works on [codepen](https://codepen.io/UmaruHime/pen/KZWbpo)

The codes I used can also be find on the link i mentioned above. I just wanna ask how to properly call the external link https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js and https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js on  the menu.php file?

This is how I did it on sublimetext. I am not sure if it is just the positioning of my files. the result on what I did is that all the text are all centered and no page flip occurring. Thanks for the  help

***Menu.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Sakurajima Menu</title>
  <link href="css/styles2.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="js/main2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/sakura-favicon.png"/>
</head>
<body>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="book-wrapper">
          <div class="book-cover">
            <img src="https://github.com/slyka85/assets/blob/master/bookcover2.png?raw=true" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="pages-container">
            <div class="pages">
              <div class="page-num-1">
                <div class="pages-content">
                  <div class="pages-background"></div>
                  <div class="content-inner">
                    <h1>Chapter 1</h1>
                    <div class="text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptas ea non vitae a assumenda sint quod, dolores laboriosam velit corrupti nobis cupiditate perspiciatis natus exercitationem, architecto esse ratione blanditiis! Itaque.</p></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="page-num-2">
                <div class="pages-content">
                  <div class="content-inner">
                    <h1>Chapter 2</h1>
                    <div class="text">
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, cumque autem! Magni eligendi qui officiis? Fugit iste voluptatum atque voluptatibus totam! Nisi accusantium saepe hic. Aut nobis nesciunt mollitia error.</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam odio modi, hic ratione fugit quod natus, excepturi quae minus voluptatum cupiditate quia magnam eveniet ex, reiciendis voluptates ipsam iste laudantium!</p>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati deserunt magnam, at perspiciatis aut. Voluptatem consequuntur neque quisquam?</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="page-num-3">
                <div class="pages-content">
                  <div class="content-inner">
                    <h1>Chapter 3</h1>
                    <div class="text"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate voluptas molestiae tempore amet adipisci dicta incidunt nisi alias distinctio fugit blanditiis dignissimos nobis deserunt eum consequuntur ipsam, perspiciatis numquam repellendus.</p>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus in odio deserunt est hic minima inventore, mollitia, officia aspernatur eaque voluptatibus? Amet, molestias adipisci delectus ea eligendi sit numquam illo.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="page-num-4">
                <div class="pages-content">
                  <div class="content-inner">
                    <h1>The End</h1>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put first the vendor libraries

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: wow it worked. Is that always the format? Vendor first then the main js file?

Comment: You need to load to `javascript` at the end of `body` to load your page faster. `jquery.min.js` should load first because `TweenMax.min.js` is using `jQuery` and `main2.js` should load last because it is using both `jquery.min.js` and `TweenMax.min.js`

Comment: with that said, should i declare the javascript after body. That's my understanding right? that only applies to javascript right>